# Why does my setter not work

Tags: wpf, xaml

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Tabs}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTab, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="15">
            <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ContentControl Content="{Binding Title}">
                        <ContentControl.Style>
                            <Style>
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Orange"></Setter>
                            </Style>
                        </ContentControl.Style>
                    </ContentControl>
...more code
```

In the above, I'm trying to style a tabcontrol, in particular the tab itself.

The issue is trying to set a background colour for the entire tab item. XAML doesn't like the `Setter Property="Background"` bit.

I'm not asking some one to to fix it (per-se), but *why* XAML doesn't like it (so I can understand it).

My understanding is (and this is where I need guidance): I know `Background` is a valid property of `ContentControl`, so from there, we can tell WPF we are accessing it's style via `ContentControl.Style` - Now, it is expecting a style, so we provide a `style` tag and then the `setter`.

> Cannot resolve the Style Property 'Background'. Verify that the owning type is the Style's TargetType, or use Class.Property syntax to specify the Property.

Can some one explain where my thinking is incorrect please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it doesn't know the type where the style applies to, so you have to specify it, using the [`TargetType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.style.targettype(v=vs.110).aspx) property of the `Style`:

```
<Style TargetType="ContentControl">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Orange"></Setter>
</Style>
```

I think in your case it is easier to set the style on a higher level:

```
<TabControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="TabItem">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Orange" />
    </Style>
</TabControl.Resources>
```

Or remove the `ContentControl`:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Grid">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Orange"></Setter>
            </Style>
        </Grid.Style>

        <Label Content="{Binding Title}" />
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Aaahhhh, because of course I'm doing `ContentControl.Style` which has nothing to do with the `TabItem` (is this correct)? Meaning I'm trying to add a background to ContentControl instead of the TabItem?

Comment: You set it to a `Style` in general, it has no knowledge of the type above it.

Comment: OK, so when I do Control.Style (meaning the style of that control) the children have no idea what the parent is, so I have to explicity state it? I would have thought because the Style was a child of Control.Style that the style would be applied to the parent (if I'm making any sense)

Comment: Oddly, although this fixes the exception, the style isn't applied either!